# Тире в предложении со структурой "Если..., а"

Tags: запятые, тире

Нужно ли тире в этом предложении? Какой вариант правильный?

```
Если кошки маленькие, а собаки, которых нужно накормить - большие, то накорми собак первыми.
```

или

```
Если кошки маленькие, а собаки, которых нужно накормить, большие, то накорми собак первыми.
```

Answer (score 1):

Если кошки маленькие, а собаки, которых нужно накормить, большие, то накорми собак первыми.

Здесь нет причин для тире (нет пропущенных слов).

Если кошки маленькие, а собаки большие, то накорми собак первыми.